morita equivalent lie groupoids diagram
I hope you are doing well. I have been trying to create this diagram corresponding to Lie groupoids Morita equivalent, but I don't know how to do it. Does anyone know a way to do it using different packages that work on Overleaf? I would like to see different alternatives so I can choose the one that I consider best for my case. Thank you!


Welcome to TSE. What did you try?

With tikz:
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, matrix}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[> = {Stealth[round]}]
        \def\G{\mathcal{G}}
        
        \matrix[matrix of nodes, ampersand replacement = \&, name = M, column sep = 2em, row sep = 2em]{
            $(\G_1,\omega_1)$ \& $(Q,\varpi)$ \& $(\G_2,\omega_2)$ \\
            $(M_1,\eta_1)$ \& \& $(M_2,\eta_2)$\\
        };
        
        \tikzset{arista/.style={midway, font = \tiny, sloped, inner sep = 2pt, fill = white}}
        \draw[->] (M-1-2)--(M-2-1) node[arista] {$J_1$};
        \draw[->] (M-1-2)--(M-2-3) node[arista] {$J_2$};
        
        \tikzset{flecha/.style = {->, transform canvas={xshift=#1}}}
        \draw[flecha = -0.2em] (M-1-1)--(M-2-1);
        \draw[flecha = 0.2em] (M-1-1)--(M-2-1);
        \draw[flecha = -0.2em] (M-1-3)--(M-2-3);
        \draw[flecha = 0.2em] (M-1-3)--(M-2-3);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

you get:


It's really easy with tikz-cd, with the advantage that arrow tips will be the same as in the rest of your document.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}
(\mathcal{G}_{1},\omega_{1})
  \arrow[d,shift right]
  \arrow[d,shift left]
&
(Q,\varpi)
  \arrow[dl,"J_{1}"]
  \arrow[dr,"J_{2}"']
&
(\mathcal{G}_{2},\omega_{2})
  \arrow[d,shift right]
  \arrow[d,shift left]
\\
(M_{1},\eta_{1})
&&
(M_{2},\eta_{2})
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}

The apostrophe after the double quote closing a label moves the label to the other side of the arrow.

